# how to set up wx.TextEntryDialog button's label

Tags: wxpython

I want to set the label of the button, but there is no such method as SetOkLabel() in the wx.textenterydialog. What should I do?

Comment: How about `SetValue()`? https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.TextEntryDialog.html

Comment: Thank you, but it's not SetValue (), I want to set the label of the ok button

Comment: I have no experience using wx, but `TextEntryDialog` inherits from `Dialog`, and `Dialog` has a method `GetMainButtonIds()` https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Dialog.html#wx.Dialog.GetMainButtonIds maybe find a way to get the `Button` object by ID and change the text of the `Button`.

Comment: In regards to getting the object by ID https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Window.html#wx.Window.FindWindowById